# Error when adding an export to CSV button to Ruby On Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im getting the following error when adding a export to CSV button on my Hotel Model.

```
Missing template hotels/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:csv], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/kallan1/Desktop/GSW-CRM/app/views"
  * "/Users/kallan1/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in the question?

Comment: how did you "adding a export to CSV button"? what does the code to handle the response to the button looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Rails expects to find views (e.g. html files) for the `hotels/index, application/index` (controller) actions. Did you define the appropriate view files?

**EDIT** Seems like a problem in your controller responses. This is *approximately* what you should have in the controller's `index` definition:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @users.to_csv, filename: "example.csv" } # fill these with appropriate names
end
```

Comment: Both Application and Hotels have the index.html.erb files.

Comment: Could you post the controllers' `index` definitions?